# AJAX Keyword Suggestion Tool

Tags: domains, javascript, keywords, meta-keywords

Are there any JavaScript includes to provide an AJAX based keyword suggestion tool based on some existing text?

For instance Yahoo offer a [Keyword Extraction Tool](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/content/V1/termExtraction.html) but due to cross-domain JavaScript policies in browsers it is not possible to provide a pure JavaScript version of this.

If a site offered a library for inclusion that would then perform the query this breaks the cross-domain restriction.

Is there such a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little unclear on the final usage as to why you're specifying AJAX, but check out [Zemanta](http://developer.zemanta.com/), which provides an API to send text to that you can query for interesting contextual information. Here are the [Zemanta docs](http://developer.zemanta.com/docs).

Is that the kind of things you're looking for?

Comment: That looks like the closest thing that could work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for what it's worth you could create a server-side script that serves as a middle-man.  Your AJAX request would send the relevant text to your script, then your script would perform an identical request to Yahoo and then pass the results back.

Comment: Unfortunately I am looking for a pure JavaScript version of this - it is easy enough to setup a Google App Engine to handle it but it seems like a more logical solution would be to have a "pure javascript" version.